# Quickbooks Online Authentication returns the "Realm id" of the sandbox company

Tags: authentication, oauth, jar, sdk, quickbooks

I managed to develop a Java web application, using Spring which connects with a Quickbooks accounting app, with the 3-legged OAuth using the "connect to Quickbooks" button. The Authentication flow seems to work fine because it returns the access token and its secret. The problem I'm having is with the realm ID, because it returns the id of the sandbox merchant for each merchant.

When I try to follow the next steps of my web application I get the following error,

com.intuit.ipp.exception.ValidationException: 
ERROR CODE:7001, 
ERROR MESSAGE:message=Subscription for company has lapsed or Invalid destination URL is used. Sandbox company works with Sandbox URL and Production company works with Production URL.; 
errorCode=007001; statusCode=400, ERROR DETAIL:null

I understand that, this is because the object I create from the DataService class of the Quickbooks is using "quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company" as the BaseURL according to the intuit-default-config.xml in the SDK.

Since I'm still in the process of developing the Application I need to fulfill the implementation using the sandbox environment and therefore the requirement is to set the baseURL to "sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/". What is the proper way to change the above configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to change the default configuration.

Need to set the property as follows, before using the DataService object.

```
Config.setProperty(Config.BASE_URL_QBO, 
"https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company");
```